# need constraints for y position, need constraints for x position

Tags: swift, xml, interface-builder

I'm trying to create a reusable textfield like view that shows the description above the textfield when there is text in the textfield. When I try the following constraints, I don't have any issue until I embed the stack view into a view.  I need the view because I want to apply the styles to that view, and I want the description and the textfield/view content to be displayed enclosed by the styled view.

This is my xib:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="18122" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES">
    <device id="retina6_1" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="18093"/>
        <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="System colors in document resources" minToolsVersion="11.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <objects>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFilesOwner" id="-1" userLabel="File's Owner" customClass="FormView" customModule="InToOut" customModuleProvider="target"/>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="-2" customClass="UIResponder"/>
        <view contentMode="scaleToFill" id="iN0-l3-epB">
            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="394" height="233"/>
            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
            <subviews>
                <view contentMode="scaleToFill" ambiguous="YES" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="6MT-Kf-be6">
                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="394" height="233"/>
                    <subviews>
                        <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" axis="vertical" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="eXL-HZ-eBt">
                            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="394" height="233"/>
                            <subviews>
                                <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Label" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="2m5-ox-32Z">
                                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="394" height="20.5"/>
                                    <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemYellowColor"/>
                                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                    <nil key="textColor"/>
                                    <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                </label>
                                <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="pvU-v7-kCR">
                                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="20.5" width="394" height="212.5"/>
                                    <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemOrangeColor"/>
                                    <constraints>
                                        <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="212.5" id="Ra7-Fa-LuZ"/>
                                    </constraints>
                                </view>
                            </subviews>
                            <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemGreenColor"/>
                        </stackView>
                    </subviews>
                    <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemYellowColor"/>
                    <constraints>
                        <constraint firstItem="eXL-HZ-eBt" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="6MT-Kf-be6" secondAttribute="top" id="DrL-7d-1nd"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="eXL-HZ-eBt" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="6MT-Kf-be6" secondAttribute="leading" id="Zra-Wo-zbi"/>
                        <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="eXL-HZ-eBt" secondAttribute="bottom" id="rDg-kX-Cyw"/>
                        <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="eXL-HZ-eBt" secondAttribute="trailing" id="uVW-rD-C8t"/>
                    </constraints>
                </view>
            </subviews>
            <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="vUN-kp-3ea"/>
            <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemBackgroundColor"/>
            <freeformSimulatedSizeMetrics key="simulatedDestinationMetrics"/>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="-21.739130434782609" y="344.53125"/>
        </view>
    </objects>
    <resources>
        <systemColor name="systemBackgroundColor">
            <color white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
        </systemColor>
        <systemColor name="systemGreenColor">
            <color red="0.20392156862745098" green="0.7803921568627451" blue="0.34901960784313724" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
        </systemColor>
        <systemColor name="systemOrangeColor">
            <color red="1" green="0.58431372549019611" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
        </systemColor>
        <systemColor name="systemYellowColor">
            <color red="1" green="0.80000000000000004" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
        </systemColor>
    </resources>
</document>
```

Here is my xib's class:

```swift
import UIKit

class FormView: NibView {

}
```

Here is my definition of NibView

````swift
import UIKit

/// NibView is provided to reuse nib initialization code.
/// **Steps to use:**
/// 1. Create a swift file for your custom view, make your custom view a sub class of NibView like so
/// ```
/// class MyCustomView: NibView {
/// ```
/// 2.  Create a corresponding  xib file for your custom View: `⌘ n  →  View  →  Next`
/// 3.  Open your xib, select the `file owner` under `PlaceHolders` in the second most left tab,
/// then once selected, click on the identity inspector, the 4th column in the right most tab, and type
/// the name of your custom view, it should autopopulate as you type.  You do not need the view to be
/// a subclass of `MyCustomView` in the identity inspector, only the file Owner.
@IBDesignable class NibView: UIView {
    var view: UIView!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        xibSetup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        xibSetup()
    }

    func xibSetup() {
        backgroundColor = .clear
        guard let nibView = loadNib() else {
            assertionFailure("Could not load the nib")
            return
        }
        view = nibView
        inject(view: view)
    }
}

extension UIView {

    /// Inserts a subview and constrains it to fill this view (the superview) by default.
    ///  Using string formats supports older OS.  This has an early exit if the
    /// view is already injected.  This also clears the subViews before injecting.
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - view: The view you are injecting
    func inject(view: UIView) {
        guard !subviews.contains(view) else { return }
        if subviews.count > 0 { subviews.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview() }}
        view.frame = bounds
        addSubview(view)
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        [
            topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor),
            rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor),
            bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
        ].forEach {
            $0.isActive = true
        }
    }

    func loadNib() -> UIView? {
        type(of: self).description().components(separatedBy: ".").last.flatMap {
            UINib(nibName: $0, bundle: Bundle(for: type(of: self)))
                .instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as? UIView
        }
    }
}
````

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you have provided enough constraints for your `UIStackView` that has `id="eXL-HZ-eBt"`. There are four constraints - `top`, `leading`, `bottom` & `trailing` with this id.

However the new `UIView` (with `id="6MT-Kf-be6"`) that wraps the stack view does not have any constraints specified. Although it's size can be driven by stack view size (which is driven by it's contents/subviews), you still need to provide it `top` & `leading` constraints so Autolayout can compute where it's position should be on the screen.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't provide enough code.  This is a xib.  I updated my question.

Comment: The code doesn't seem to add the missing constraints in the XIB. You need to provide the necessary constraints to the view that wraps the stackView and is the only child of the main/parent view in the XIB. The code extracts the top level view and apply necessary constraints to that. It does not add anything to stackView's superview that's creating the issue here.